# How to check character values on a String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I was asked to write a Java program which gets 5 strings from user and collects it in an array. Furthermore, I need to check every single string in the array and only print the ones who has more than four characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner mbk = new Scanner(System.in);
    int repetition[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    String words[] = new String[repetition.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter element " + repetition[i] + ":");
        words[i] = mbk.nextLine();
    }
}
```

This is the code that I have written and I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: *I'm stuck* stuck with what? what is the problem?

Comment: You need to do another loop, an `if` check for the length and another `System.out.println`  basically you need to do more of what you have done already. NOTE: You don't need an array for `repetition`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Tidy code, nice. I just have one suggestion: we have left the age in which we use weird abbreviations to name our variables. Your code should immediately be readable by other developers. So what does `mbk` mean? Maybe you can replace it with an expressive name?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length() > 4).forEach(System.out::println)` :o)

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks again for the heads up about the mbk stuff, it is the initials of my name so I wasn't able to notice the difficulty for you guys. I was able to finish the code where I was stucked. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, It's a very bad practice to use variable names like `mbk`, the variable name should be easily understood by any other developer reading your code. It's name should reflect it's purpose. Here's a small revision of your code.

Also, Leaving a I/O stream open can cause you a big time of trouble, so i have also added the `scanner.close` statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxArrayLength[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    String words[] = new String[maxArrayLength.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter element " + maxArrayLength[i] + ":");
            words[i] = userInput.nextLine();
        }

    for(int lengthCheckCounter = 0; lengthCheckCounter < words.length; lengthCheckCounter++)
        if(words[lengthCheckCounter].length() > 4)
            System.out.println(words[lengthCheckCounter] + "-" + words[lengthCheckCounter].length());
        userInput.close();
}
```

Another way of closing the I/O stream/resources could be to use `try-with-resources` block featured since `JDK 1.7`. Then we can write your code as follows:

```
try(Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // All other code
}
```

If you are on `JDK 1.8`, you can use a single line to do everything as suggested in Lonely Neuron's comment:

```
// Initialize your words array here
// Take user input
// Print words greater than 4 using JDK 1.8 Filter below
Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length() > 4).forEach(System.out::println)
```

Comment: Thank you for your wise help, I was able to finish the code. I will consider your suggestions in my further projects.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: The `scanner.close()` here is wrong, since you didn't open the scanner. `System.in` was opened for you (by the operating system), and it isn't your responsibility to close it. If you had opened the scanner on a file, for example, then that would be different.

Answer (score 0):

`words[j].length()` will give you the length of the string in index `j` of your array. I am leaving you to compare it to 4, And to introduce a variable `j` (you may call it `i` again or any other name you find fitting).

Answer (score 0):

Yo, I gotchu:

this goes through the entire list, and prints anything that has a greater length than 4.

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    if (yourArray[i].length() > 4) {
         System.out.println(yourArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code solved the exact problem that I needed to solve.

Comment: @Mesut Berk Karataş did my comment answer the question, or the one above me?

Comment: I saw your comment first and it has worked, I tried the comment above as well.

Comment: Ah, ok. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `length()` method

```
for(String s: words){
    if(s.length()>=4){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to finish it at last!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOf4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] names=new String[5];


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {


            System.out.println("Enter a string:");
            names[i]=scn.nextLine();

        }

        System.out.println("The strings with more than 4 characters are: ");

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

            if(names[i].length()>4)
            System.out.println(names[i]);

        }


    }


}
```